# window becomes blurry/pixelated when run from .app

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have made a small python script which runs a clock on a QtWidget and everything works fine.

I wanted to make an executable with it, therefore I used pyinstaller and everything works from the code's perspective.

Though, when I create a .app (macOS) (using the -w option) and run the script using this app the quality of the window and its content become much worse as if blurred/pixelated. And weirdly if I pull out the script from .app/Contents/MacOS/ and run it from a folder outside the app the quality is normal again.

see screenshots:

Normal quality

[image]

Bad quality

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? And/Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the 'NSHighResolutionCapable' to 'True' within the info.plist file of the app should do the trick.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>port_poirot</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MacOS/port_poirot</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>detective.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>port_poirot</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>port_poirot</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.0</string>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <string>True</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Altering the spec file of pyinstaller make it a bit easier.
See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-options-for-a-mac-os-x-bundle

Comment: I'll definitely try that! Thanks for the answer